# Get properties of ndb model instance where Python name != datastore name

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

**Goal:** get "Python names" of attributes from an instance of Example, where the model was defined with a different datastore name

To provide some context, I have a custom `to_dict()` method for serializing an NDB Model. The core of the method is as follows:

```python
for key, prop in self._properties.iteritems():
    if hasattr(self, key):
        value = getattr(self,key)
        # do typical to_dict() stuff
```

If a model is defined as follows, everything is fine:

```python
import Thing 
class Example(ndb.Model):
    things = ndb.KeyProperty(Thing, repeated=True)
```

However, there are issues if it defined where the the Python name is `things` but the datastore name is `'Thing'`:

```python
# no import req'd
class Example(ndb.Model):
    things = ndb.KeyProperty('Thing', repeated=True)
```

In the first scenario, the `key` from `self._properties.iteritems()` would be `things`. If I have an instance of Example, say `example`, then `hasattr(example,'things')` would evaluate to True.

In the second scenario, the `key` would be `Thing` and `hasattr(example,'Thing')` would evaluate to False, since the instance of Example has attributes defined by the Python name 'things'.

How can I get the properties of the instance? TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ndb`'s own `Model._to_dict` method does it as follows (simplifying):

```
for prop in self._properties.itervalues():
  name = prop._code_name
  values[name] = prop._get_for_dict(self)
```

So: the name is taken from the `_code_name` of each property (not its key in `self._properties`, and the value is delegated to the property itself (via its `_get_for_dict` method) to allow further tweaking.

As a result, coding both of your examples as Example1 and Example2, whole their `_properties.items()` are respectively:

```
[('things', KeyProperty('things', repeated=True, kind='Thing'))]
[('Thing', KeyProperty('Thing', repeated=True))]
```

their `._to_dict()`, as desired, both equal

```
{'things': [Key('Thing', 'roro')]}
```

Comment: A key to this answer is the `.itervalues()`.  If just iterating through `self._properties`, each `prop` will be a string, which then won't have attributes like `_code_name` or `_verbose_name`